# How to go through a proxy server with SeleniumVBA

Tags: vba, selenium, proxy, selenium-chromedriver, xmlhttprequest

I wrote below function to go through a proxy server.

```vb
' Thisworkbook::set_proxy
Public Sub set_proxy(ByRef client As MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60)

  ' use_proxy, proxy_server, proxy_user and proxy_password are global valiable.

    If Not use_proxy Then Exit Sub
    With client
        .setProxy 2, proxy_server
        .setProxyCredentials proxy_user, proxy_password
    End With

End Sub
```

And, I added `Call Thisworkbook.set_proxy(client)` just before every `client.send` in `WebDriver.cls`.

But, Chrome display authentication dialog for proxy, so can not connect to internet.

Please show me that how to go through a proxy server with SeleniumVBA.